# WP confusing "links to my articles" with "comments"?

Tags: comments

I added a new article in my WordPress blog. In this article I included a link to one of my previous articles in the same blog. That article then informed me that I had a new comment. The comment was actually the link to it from my new entry. I went ahead and approved it and now that article says "*one comment*" underneath, but theres no comment there.

I am pretty new to having a WP blog, so I don't know if its a WP bug, a feature, or something I did wrong.

Comment: By the way: what Theme are you using?

Comment: @Chip cleanr by WPShoppe. My blog is here: http://programming-perils.com/

Comment: I just updated my answer, with information specific to your Theme.

Answer (score 4):

What it notified was actually not a comment but a [Pingback](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pingbacks). Often themes list both comments and pingbacks/trackbacks in the same spot, but you could cutomize that to have both a comments section and a pingback/trackback section.

Comment: Chip Bennet is right, it's a Pinkback, not a trackback, though they are almost similar.

Answer (score 3):

That "link to your article" is a *pingback*, and is a valid comment type in WordPress.

There are two issues:

1. Apparently, your Theme isn't configured to display pingbacks/trackbacks in the comment list
2. The WordPress function `get_comments_number()` counts *all* comments, rather than just *comment*-type comments. You can filter it, if you want, so that it returns *just* the number of comments, rather than the total number of comments and pings.

Use something like the following (in your functions.php file):

```
/**
 * Filter 'get_comments_number'
 * 
 * Filter 'get_comments_number' to display correct 
 * number of comments (count only comments, not 
 * trackbacks/pingbacks)
 * 
 * @link    http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/display-the-most-accurate-comment-count-in-wordpress/ WPBeginner
 */
function mytheme_comment_count( $count ) {  
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        global $id;
        $comments_by_type = &separate_comments(get_comments('status=approve&post_id=' . $id));
        return count($comments_by_type['comment']);
    } else {
        return $count;
    }
}
add_filter('get_comments_number', 'mytheme_comment_count', 0);
```

Then `get_comments_number()` will return just the number of comments.

**EDIT:**

[Your Theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/cleanr) (which, by the way, hasn't been updated in the Repository in almost two years) is designed only to output *comment*-type comments. [See here, in `comments.php`](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/cleanr/0.1.2/comments.php):

```
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=cleanr_theme_comment'); ?>
</ol>
```

You'll either need to modify the code, or switch to a Theme that supports listing trackbacks/pingbacks.